# container inside a container in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, containers

I have a Java program that has a `BorderLayout` and so far is working fine.
I want to add a `JTextArea` below that to display out put after I hit the run button.

Can some one show me an example of the BEST way to accomplish what I want to do?
Should I define a `GridLayout` of 2X1 with my `BorderLayout` up top and then my `JTextArea` underneath that?

I am open to suggestions...

here is an image of what I have so far:
[image]

below this -- I want to have a text area that will capture the out put once I click the run button.

Comment: it will be helpful if you put some of the code what you have done so far.

Comment: I have not posted any code because what I have tried so far blows up. I really want to know the basic idea of how I should lay this out.  I learn best by see general examples and trying them out for myself.

Comment: ..or better still a screenshot of what you have and a drawing of what you want.

Comment: May I suggest to use JSplitPane. On the down side, you can add a JTextArea and on upper side you can add your other component.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of what you're trying to do, but you can have JPanels as children of JPanels.  Sometimes, nested JPanels allow you to use different layout managers on different parts of your GUI.

Comment: Give a better ideia, where ecactly would this JTextArea would be? down the whole thing?

Comment: do you have added all these components on a `panel` or `frame`?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal - I have these components on a panel.  That is how I added them to the border layout in the different locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in my comment...what about something like this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;



public class Ironmantis extends JFrame{
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    JPanel upperPanel = new JPanel();
    JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,upperPanel,new JScrollPane(textArea));

    public Ironmantis(){
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.append("Operating system: "+System.getProperty("os.name")+"\n");
        textArea.append("Operating System version: " +System.getProperty("os.version")+"\n");
        textArea.append("Operating system architecture: "+ System.getProperty("os.arch")+"\n");
        textArea.append("Java version: "+ System.getProperty("java.version")+"\n");
        textArea.append("Java vendor: "+ System.getProperty("java.vendor")+"\n");
        textArea.append("Java vendor URL: "+ System.getProperty("java.vendor.url")+"\n");
        upperPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,400));
        upperPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        splitPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        add(splitPane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Ironmantis i = new Ironmantis();
                i.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                i.pack();
                i.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

[image]

By adding your `JPanel` and `JTextArea` on `JSplitPane`, your `JTextArea` will be in role of some kind of console, which is, if I understood correctly, goal of your question.

Comment: very interesting.  
Let me ask this -- I already have the elements of the borderlayout as panel is different class files.  How do I get the borderlayouta s a panel so I can add it to the JSplitPane?

I am trying out all solutions to see what fits best ....

Comment: I tried your solution and my GUI on top does not look like what I have pictured above in my original question.

here is my code:

Comment: so far -- this is working for me.
Thanks everyone for the pointers!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't answer you immediately. I'm glad you found solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

If I got the idea, you want to add a TextArea below the whole thing when you hit the run button.

I suggest to use 2 panels. Put all you have already in a Panel (this panel would have the borderLayout) and then put another panel below that, where you'd programmatically add the JtextArea when you hit the Run button.

**EDIT**
Something like:

```
Window
|
|--- Panel  (borderLayout)
|      | --- (things you already have)
|
|--- Panel 2
     | ---- (JTextArea, added later by code)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.

I already have the BorderLayout with the panel elements in them.  Do I need to then set this in a panel (how do I do that by the way??)? and THEN add another panel that has the JTextArea??

Comment: Your window would have two panels one on top and another in the bottom. The top one would have the borderLayout and the stuff yoou showed here. 

The other one would have the JTextArea (added later by code in the button listener).

Answer (score 1):

use the `border layout`.
Add your existing GUI to a `panel` and add it on the `center` of the `frame` and your `TextArea` on the `south` of `border layout`.

a code snippet:

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);  //panel== your existing GUI
frame.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, textArea);  //new TextArea
```

Comment: @Muhammed Faisal:  thanks for the suggestion. I still have some learning to do ... forgive me as I am still a Java newbie

Comment: @Muhammed Faisal:  thanks for the code snippets... these really help me out a lot.